# SSMS 2017 is not showing server name

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssms-2017

I installed SQL server 2017 but I am not able to connect it because Server Name is not showing, its showing blank. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer. From Visual studio 2017 I tried to connect SQL server, from there I got the server name. I copied the same server name and used in SSMS. Now I am able to connect SSMS. :)[image]

Comment: Now Visual studio 2017 fully support SQL Server.